# How to change ownership of a local GIT repository on Windows 11

Tags: windows, permissions, repository, git-for-windows

I am a relatively new/light GIT user. I use a local git repository to backup my code and I have not setup a remote repository on github.com or any other remote repository hosting system. I am working on Windows 10 & Windows 11 machines.

I created a local git repository using `git init` which created a **.git** folder under my project directory. I moved the **.git** folder so created to a USB thumb drive (D:) and renamed it **myrepo**. In my project directory I created a *.git* file with the setting `gitdir: D:/myrepo`. My though process was in case my C: drive fails I will have my local repository safe on the USB thumb drive as I have not setup a remote repository. All worked well with this setup.

Now I have a new machine (Windows 11). I copied my project code to the new machine and plugged in the USB thumb drive (D:). However when I execute any git commands I get an error -- *fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository....*. After some research I found out that due to a recent git security vulnerability an update to git causes it to check for repository ownership before executing commands.

One easy solution is to add a **safe.directory** setting `git config --global -add safe.directory <project directory>`. But I am trying to get to the bottom of this. ON WINDOWS PLATFORM - How does git know the owner of the local repository? As mentioned the local repository is on a USB thumb drive which is a FAT32 partition and does not have any kind of file ownership. So how does git know the repository was created by some other user? Also is there a way to change the ownership of the git local repository so that I don't have to use the **safe.directory** setting.

Thank you in advance for any help the community can offer.

Comment: I do not think that git does much guessing. It only checks for OS-level ownership of the files of the repo (going against the user that is running git) and from there it complains.

Comment: _"I created a .git file"_ - why?

Comment: Git-for-Windows uses the OS's "who owns the file" SID calls. When applied to file systems that don't support these, it just deems them unsafe. To avoid that, copy the files to a file system that's safe (or override the safety check with `safe.directory`).

Comment: To answer @evolutionxbox - as I mentioned since I have not setup a remote repository I wanted to keep the code and local repository on separate media.

Comment: In response to @torek - If that were the case I would get this same error on my old machine no? After all even there the thumb drive is a FAT32 partition so has no permissions so the SID call would return "unknown" or something like that. But It works fine on the old machine without safe.directory setting.

Comment: @torek you are CORRECT!!! Thank you very much!! So my old machine had a slightly older version of git. But when I upgraded it to the latest version I have the same issue. Thus affirming your response.

Answer (score 3):

No need to create a new folder (you need local admin for the following). First right click the solution folder click properties->security tab and then the Advanced button. At the top you will see the name of the object and owner with a link to Change the owner. Click on Change and type in your username. This will change the solution folders ownership to you. Then finally enable viewing of hidden files and do the same for the .git folder and it should all work.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue when having taken over a machine from a colleague that left. After try and error with changing the original user data in some of the config files in the .git directory I realized it must have to do with ownership of the OS (Windows). So I copied (not moved) the whole directory (including all hidden subdirectories (important!)) into a fresh directory, deleted the original directory and renamed the fresh directory to the original name. Now all files in that directory were owned by me (because the copy operation creates new files with ownership of the one who creates the copy). Git/SourceTree quit complaining.